# How can I extract equations from docx files?

Tags: ms-office

I want to write a program to retrieves equations (formulas) from .docx files. I am using open xml sdk, but I can't see how an equation is inserted in .docx files. An image (which represent the equation) is the only thing that I can find there. How can I extract equations from .docx files? Is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

The previous answer was not responsive to the question!

If you examine the xml document tree and open the file document.xml, you will see something like the following:

```
<m:oMath><m:r><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:ascii="Cambria Math" w:hAnsi="Cambria Math"/></w:rPr><m:t>x= y</m:t>
```

(In the above example, the equation is "x=y".  The tag  indicates an equation.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to select the text in each equation editor object an copy it out to another document or something by following the VBA section in this link:

http://www.extendoffice.com/documents/word/751-word-select-equation.html

That's what I'd try anyway!